# Define a conditional format rule based on a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to define a conditional format rule based on a formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(TableFerias[Colaborador];[@Coluna1];TableFerias[Data];Calendário!C5)>0
```

But Excel doesn't let me do this:

[image]

Comment: Are you even able to type this formula somewhere in your Excel sheet? If yes, what are the meanings of "TableFerias", "Colarobador" :-), "Calendário", ...?

Comment: Yes, sure, the formula is fine. TableFerias is a table and Colaborador is a column of that table.